# Sorting a list of the form [(single value), [(tuple 1), (tuple2), ...], (another value),[...]]

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm not sure what the best way to write a title for this question is, so sorry for the somewhat poor title. Instead, I'll just write an example.

What I want to do is take the items from a dictionary and place them in a list, (which I have done with the following code).

```
for key,val in teamDict.items(): teamlist.append((key,val))
```

Now this list contains info on teams in the NFL, and is stored in the form:

```
[('DAL', [(2011, 'Chauncey Washington', 47.29080932784636, 1, -1, 0, 0), (2011, 'DeMarco Murray', 90.58014654220617, 164, 897, 2, 1)...]]
```

And so on, with every team being represented. 
Now what I want is for the output to look something like this

```
Roy Helu                   2011     81.33
Ryan Torain                2011     78.16
Tim Hightower              2011     84.20
Andre Brown                2010     50.03
Brandon Banks              2010     69.24
Clinton Portis             2010    108.35
```

Only for every player from 2011 to be printed after every player from 2010 has been printed. Everything is formatted correctly and printing out correctly, the only trouble I'm running into is not being able to get the years sorted properly. Also here is the code that sorts through the list:

```
for item in teamlist:
    for sub_item in item:
        teamName = item[0]
    if user_input == teamName:
        for sub_sub_item in sub_item:
            print("    {:<25} {:^6} {:>8.2f}".format(sub_sub_item[1], sub_sub_item[0], sub_sub_item[2]))
```

I know about the key = operator.itemgetter() option, but I'm not sure if that would even work for a list like this or where to put it in my for loops.

Any hints to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: To turn key-value pairs from a dictionary into a list of tuples, do `my_dict.items()`. If you are on Python 3, then do `list(my_dict.items())`.

Comment: Just to be clear, we are only printing out one team at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for item in teamlist:
    for sub_item in item:
        teamName = item[0]
    if user_input == teamName:
        sorted_lists = [x for x in zip(*sorted(zip(sub_item), key=lambda x: x[0]))]
        for sub_sub_item in sorted_lists[0]:
            print("    {:<25} {:^6} {:>8.2f}".format(sub_sub_item[1], sub_sub_item[0], sub_sub_item[2]))
```

If you are not a big fan of lambda, then you can use operator's itemgetter method which is as:

```
sorted_lists = [x for x in zip(*sorted(zip(sub_item), key=operator.itemgetter(0)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite certain what you want to sort on, but take a look at the documentation, i.e. https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting.

You can supply a function to sorted, to determine the key to sort by, so to sort `[(2011, 'Chauncey Washington', 47.29080932784636, 1, -1, 0, 0), (2011, 'DeMarco Murray', 90.58014654220617, 164, 897, 2, 1)...]` by year you could call

```
from operator import itemgetter
...
sorted(yourList, key=itemgetter(0))
```

or with a lambda

```
sorted(yourList, key= lambda item: item[0] )
```

For more complex sorts look at the section `Sort Stability and Complex Sorts` from the link above. Basically you start sorting by the least important keys, and then do stable sorts for the more important sort keys till you reach the most important one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the elements within each inner tuple are already in the correct order for sorting (that is, most significant element first), so the simplest is to sort them as you are building `teamlist`:

```
for key, val in teamDict.items():
    teamlist.append((key, sorted(val)))
```

This is a simple enough loop that you could make it a list comprehension if you like:

```
teamlist = [(key, sorted(val)) for key, val in teamDict.items()]
```

Comment: There is a slight problem in that the output seems sorted by descending year, and ascending name.

Comment: @Dunes: I don't know how you're getting that result. When I try my solution on test data that looks like OP's, it comes out in ascending year, and within a given year, in ascending player name.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I was referring to the sample output given in the question. Your code sorts by ascending order for all values in the tuple. Seeing as this looks like a homework-esque assignment, I believe the difference of descending year and ascending name is intentional.

Comment: @Dunes: Did you read the text of the question? In particular, after the example output he gives, he then says "Only for every player from 2011 to be printed after every player from 2010 has been printed."